# Piece of code causes game to freeze, then keep playing after sometime

Tags: unity, c#, debugging

### Games Basic Premise

Ball rolls along procedurally generated path. Click to changer directions. Don't fall off. I have a script dedicated to the path. The path is made up of 20 cubes, along the x+ and z+ axis. Path is generated at the start then changes randomly as you go.

### Problem

In my path designer script, I also control another cube I call "Fake Path". It's a single cube to throw off the player. But whenever the control script runs it freezes my game, I'm assuming it's processing something. Then after awhile it **might** resume the game. I know my code is probably a little wonky since I'm still getting the basics of game design. `Key_CircLinkList` is a circular linked list. With each element storing an index.

```
void Start(){
    sphere = GameObject.Find("Sphere");
    sphereScript = sphere.GetComponent<SphereMove>();
    startingCube = GameObject.Find("StartCube");
    fakeCube = GameObject.Find("FakeCube");
    randIndex = 10;
    isGenerated = true;

    pathV2 = new Key_CircLinkList<GameObject>();
    pathV2.AddFirst(startingCube);

    for (int i = 0; i < pathLength-1; i++)
    {
        float random = Random.value;
        pathV2.AddLast(Instantiate(startingCube, this.transform));
        if (random <= 0.5f)
        {
            pathV2.GetLast().GetElement().transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(i).GetElement().transform.position.x + distMove, pathV2.SelectInd(i).GetElement().transform.position.y, pathV2.SelectInd(i).GetElement().transform.position.z);
            //Setting initial movement direction
            if (i == 0)
            {
                sphereScript.l_or_r = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pathV2.GetLast().GetElement().transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(i).GetElement().transform.position.x, pathV2.SelectInd(i).GetElement().transform.position.y, pathV2.SelectInd(i).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
            //Setting initial movement direction
            if (i == 0)
            {
                sphereScript.l_or_r = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x > 
        pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x)
    {
        if (pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext(2).GetElement().transform.position.z > pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z){
            fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x + distMove, 
                                                      pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                      pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z);
        }else{
            fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x, 
                                                      pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                      pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
        }
    }else{
        if (pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext(2).GetElement().transform.position.x > pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x){
            fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x, 
                                                      pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                      pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
        }else{
            fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x + distMove, 
                                                      pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                      pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    isGenerated = false;
    cubeX = pathV2.GetLast().GetElement().transform.position.x;
    cubeZ = pathV2.GetLast().GetElement().transform.position.z;

    updatedX = cubeX;
    updatedZ = cubeZ;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    SpawnCube();
}

private void SpawnCube()
{
    float random = Random.value;
    //Updates path to move cubes by seeing if (position of the first cube) < ((position of the sphere) - however long the trail of cubes should be)
    if ((pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.x + pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.z) < ((sphere.transform.position.x + sphere.transform.position.z) - 5.0f))
    {
        if (random <= 0.5f)
        {
            updatedX = updatedX + distMove;
            pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position = new Vector3(updatedX, pathV2.GetSelect().GetPrev().GetElement().transform.position.y, updatedZ);
        }
        else
        {
            updatedZ = updatedZ + distMove;
            pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position = new Vector3(updatedX, pathV2.GetSelect().GetPrev().GetElement().transform.position.y, updatedZ);
        }
        pathV2.Rotate(1);
    }


    if(isGenerated == false){
        randIndex = pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext(10).GetIndex();
        prevIndex = randIndex;
        isGenerated = true;
        Debug.Log("Random Index: " + randIndex);
    }

    if ((fakeCube.transform.position.x + fakeCube.transform.position.z) + 2 < (sphere.transform.position.x + sphere.transform.position.z) && 
        ((pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x + pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z) > (sphere.transform.position.x + sphere.transform.position.z))
       ){
        if (pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x > pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x){
            if(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext(2).GetElement().transform.position.z > pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z){
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x+distMove, 
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z);
            }
            else{
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x,
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
            }
        }else{
            if (pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext(2).GetElement().transform.position.x > pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x)
            {
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x, 
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
            }
            else
            {
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x + distMove, 
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z);
            }
        }
        isGenerated = false;
    }
}
```

When this bit runs, it freezes:

```
if ((fakeCube.transform.position.x + fakeCube.transform.position.z) + 2 < (sphere.transform.position.x + sphere.transform.position.z) && 
        ((pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x + pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z) > (sphere.transform.position.x + sphere.transform.position.z))
       ){
        if (pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x > pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x){
            if(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext(2).GetElement().transform.position.z > pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z){
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x+distMove, 
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z);
            }
            else{
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x,
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
            }
        }else{
            if (pathV2.SelectInd(randIndex).GetNext(2).GetElement().transform.position.x > pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x)
            {
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetNext().GetElement().transform.position.x, 
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z + distMove);
            }
            else
            {
                fakeCube.transform.position = new Vector3(pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.x + distMove, 
                                                          pathV2.GetSelect().GetElement().transform.position.y, 
                                                          pathV2.SelectInd(prevIndex).GetElement().transform.position.z);
            }
        }
        isGenerated = false;
    }
```

Any help as to what to do, and maybe tips, that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see what steps it's performing during the delay?

Comment: I have not, I'll give that a go.

Comment: Unrelated tip, I strongly recommend not using GameObject.Find, if you rename your gameobject in the hierarchy your script will break. Use a public (or [SerializeField] private) field and assign the reference in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally started with an array, everything worked fine. I changed to a `Linked List` to allow for easier implementation of the path. But I decided to switch back to the `Array` implementation. I was reading online that `Linked List`'s are slower than an array, especially with `MonoBehavior`. And what I assume, is that it's so much slower, that when I would run that piece of code, it would take much longer than the `Array`. To the point where it would freeze until it finished. I took @DMGregory advice to use a breakpoint to see what my code was doing. And it worked normally, but with the extended time it took to finish.